# Calling java code from stand-alone native code

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, dalvik

In android OS I want to call an user defined java class API from a standalone code.

i.e. If there is a class "HelloWorldActivity" which has "getint" API . I would like to call this from a native app "nativecaller"

I found post related to this however I was not clear how the implementation was done.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/_JidHzVWHM8

So here is the code snippet:

```
#include <jni.h> 
#include <cutils/log.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    JavaVM *jvm;
    JNIEnv *env;
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    JavaVMOption options[1];
   options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=/data/";
   vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
   vm_args.options = options;
   vm_args.nOptions = 1;    
   vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_FALSE;

   /* Create the Java VM */    
   int res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, &env, &vm_args); 

   if(!res){    
           /* invoke the Main.test method using the JNI */    
           jclass cls = env->FindClass("com/abc/mypackage/HelloWorld"); //it is not able to find the class

        if(!cls)LOGE("\n\n\nclass not found!!!");    
         else{
           jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(cls, "getint", "(V)I");    
           env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, mid,10);    
           }

           /* We are done. */    
           jvm->DestroyJavaVM();

    }
   else    
   LOGE("\n\n\n\n CreateJAVAVM failed!!");      
}
```

`FindClass` is returning `null`.

1.Is it possible to access class inside an activity (an apk)

2.What should -Djava.class.path point to ?

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: class path is the path to the .class files. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29

Comment: Yes it is.But in my case the class I am reffering to is inside apk , as classes.dex. So a bit clueless here!!

Comment: I guess you can't use classes from an apk from within a standalone native tool. This also does not sound useful since the apk / app would not be running so any method you would manage to call would not return you useful data. If you want to use native code inside a running app you have to use the standard NDK ways that execute native code from within a running app with existing JVM.

Comment: @zapl - that's not really true.  An apk is just a special jar (containing dex rather than java classes), however the file itself may not be readable to foreign user ID's on some Android versions.  fadden also points out a possible permission issue with the cache, but if one is starting the process from scratch there are workarounds for that.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes, apk is kind of a jar with a .dex instead of classes. But apk is certainly not accessible w/o root and I'm thinking the intention here is to call some methods on an existing instance of `HelloWorldActivity` which isn't going to work by spawning a new dalvik instance.

Comment: Existing instance?  Doesn't seem like what this is asking, but if it is it's actually easier - use IPC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dalvik provides a command called `dalvikvm`, which isn't too far removed from what you're trying to do.  It's just a command-line wrapper for `libdvm.so` (try `adb shell dalvikvm -help`).  You can see the source code [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/jb-mr2-release/dalvikvm/Main.cpp).

Try a quick test: instead of looking up your application class, look up something that you know will be there (say, `java/lang/String`).  That will tell you if the VM is able to do anything at all.

On a device, `BOOTCLASSPATH` will already be configured in your environment (`adb shell printenv BOOTCLASSPATH`), but `CLASSPATH` will not.  Set the `CLASSPATH` environment variable to a colon-separated list of .jar or .apk files, not a list of directories.

You will need to run as root, so that your command-line application has permission to create an entry in `/data/dalvik-cache` for your APK.  (If such an entry already exists, you may not need to be root.)

If something doesn't work, check the logcat output for details.